# Difference between Erlang's rpc:multicall/4 vs rpc:pmap/3

Tags: concurrency, erlang, elixir, rpc

I'm currently experimenting with running some Elixir code on multiple nodes and I've used two methods: 1) `:rpc.multicall/4` & 2) `:rpc.pmap/3`.

I can see that both run the code on multiple nodes and I understand that the result of those calls is different (tuple vs list).

Are there any other important differences between the two that I'm missing or are these two functions equivalent with the only differences being how they are called and the returned value?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

They are really different from one another,

`pmap` will perform a map similar to `:list.map` (more here http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html) But with the advantage that this call will happen between nodes as long as the node is available connected and there are values on the list to perform the map.

`multicall` in other way will always perform the same call, with the same args in multiple nodes. `multicall/4` performs the same function call in all nodes connected. `multicall/5` takes an extra argument at the beginning, that is the list of the nodes that will execute the rpc.

To examplify better when we have a cluster of 3 shells

- `iex --sname node1`
- `iex --sname node2`
- `iex --sname node3`

And a we connect each other at node1 executing

```
Node.connect :"node2@mymachine"
# => false
Node.connect :"node3@mymachine"
# => false
```

We can define a function that sums 2 values and returns the value with the node that this operation was performed like this:

```
iex(node1@mymachine)> defmodule Operation do
...(node1@mymachine)>   def sum(a, b), do: {Node.self(), a + b}
...(node1@mymachine)> end
```

It's necessary to define this function inside every shell. So now it's possible to just call our pmap with multiple values and see what will happens. In my computer calling from node1 with happens this.

```
iex(node1@mymachine)> :rpc.pmap {Operation, :sum}, [1], [1,2,3]
[node3@mymachine: 2, node2@mymachine: 3, node1@mymachine: 4]
```

For each node the `sum/2` function was called with a different argument on the last position, resulting in a different output. If my last argument of `:rpc.map/3` is a list with less elements then nodes available it's not necessary going to call all the nodes. But those that are necessary to complete the operation. if I pass a lot of arguments it will return the calls in a more balanced way. You can try to execute `:rpc.pmap {Operation, :sum}, [1], Enum.to_list 1..20` on each node and see the result by yourself.

In other hand when we use `:rpc.multicall/5` You are not passing a list of arguments to be executed each of them in parallel, but the same argument to be executed in multiple Nodes at the same time. For example

```
iex(node1@mymachine)> :rpc.multicall(Operation, :sum, [2, 2], :infinity)
# => {[node1@mymachine: 4, node2@mymachine: 4, node3@mymachine: 4], []}
```

The last argument it's the timeout to be executed in each node, if this timeout is met the result of this node is not going to show in the first list of the tuple.

With `:rpc.multicall/5` it's possible to pass the list of nodes that this call will be executed as the first argument. For example if I wanna to execute only in node2 and node3 inside any node I just execute

```
iex(node1@mymachine)> :rpc.multicall([:"node2@mymachine", :"node3@mymachine"] Operation, :sum, [2, 2], :infinity)
# => {[node2@mymachine: 4, node3@mymachine: 4], []}
```

One thing to notice is that `:rpc.multicall/4` and `:rpc.pmap/3` both works without a Node in action, this is because for the erlangvm, whenever you fire a `iex` or `erl` you are already on a single node cluster.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation.

[`:rpc.multicall/5`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/rpc.html#multicall-5)

> a multicall is an RPC that is sent concurrently from one client to multiple servers. This is useful for collecting information from a set of nodes, or for calling a function on a set of nodes to achieve some side effects.

[`:rpc.pmap/3`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/rpc.html#pmap-3)

> Evaluates apply(Module, Function, [Elem|ExtraArgs]) for every element Elem in List1, in parallel. Returns the list of return values, in the same order as in List1.

So `multicall/5` will call a single function on the given set of nodes. It will give you back a tuple where the first element is a list of the results and the second element is a list of the nodes that did not complete the function for whatever reason.

Whereas `pmap/3` will be similar to calling `map`, except the work may or may not be done on a different node. It is important to know that the resulting list will still have the same order as the starting list.